# How to fix the triggering of email with attachments using concourse pipelines

Tags: email, concourse, concourse-git-resource

I am trying to get the email triggers with attachments. Which concourse resource to be used?

I have used the below question to get the email trigger working.

[How to send email via Concourse CI pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752360/how-to-send-email-via-concourse-ci-pipeline)

I would like to get the logs as attachment with the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got fixed with help from the below URL

`https://github.com/pivotalservices/concourse-pipeline-samples/blob/master/pipelines/notifications/email-with-attachments/README.md`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `email-resource` doesn't have the option for attachments. Even if it did, I'm not sure how you could get the logs from the job/task. The log would probably have to be a task output. Seems complicated.

Easiest thing to do is just linking to the build in your email, like in the example in the README

```
  - put: send-an-email
    params:
      subject_text: "Build finished: ${BUILD_PIPELINE_NAME}/${BUILD_JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_NAME}"
      body_text: "Build finished: ${ATC_EXTERNAL_URL}/teams/main/pipelines/${BUILD_PIPELINE_NAME}/jobs/${BUILD_JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NAME}"
```

Sorry my answer isn't better. Hope this helps!